# mysql join if string contains similar values

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have a table that has column Description with below values:

`His name was Jacob King`

`One of the guy was Jacob. He was taller than them`

How do I join these two rows (in MySql) since they both contain the word Jacob? There will be more rows with other words too so Jacob is not the only word than can appear in more than one row. What I want is a way of joining rows with similar words appearing in them.
I tried using left join with LIKE keyword as shown below but it didn't work since i am just looking for similar word in sentences 
`` select * from (SELECT id,description FROM `statement`) f1 `` 
`` left JOIN (SELECT id,description FROM `statement`) f2 `` 
`on f1.description like concat('%' ,f2.description,'%')`

The above doesn't work, I think because I am looking for a word as opposed to the entire sentence

Comment: You have to specify the problem exactly. What do you mean by "similar values"? Is one common word enough? Or two? Do spaces count? Does `was` count? Are `Jacob` and `jacob` the same word?

Comment: One common word is enough. Space does not count. Jacob and jacob are same word.

Answer (score 0):

You can try usinga join

```
SELECT concat (s1.description , ' ', s2.description)'
FROM `statement`  s1
INNER JOIN `statement` s2  ON s1.description like  ('%Jacob%')  
    AND  s2.description like  ('%Jacob%')
```

or using an input

```
set @my_word= 'jacob';

SELECT concat (s1.description , ' ', s2.description)'
FROM `statement`  s1
INNER JOIN `statement` s2  ON lower(s1.description)  like  concat('%', @my_word, '%')  
AND  lower(s2.description)  like  concat('%', @my_word, '%')
```

Comment: This won't work as the join word  'Jacob' can change. The one above was just a sample. The rows might have different words but there's a common word in the sentence. I want to join with that common word

Comment: also  'was' is in common between the descriptions ..  why 'Jacod' and not 'was' ....  ?????   .  you have an imput word for the the query??